# Configuring flyway to use Oracle wallet

Tags: oracle, flyway

I am trying to configure flyway to work with oracle wallet.
I have done below configuation in conf file.
flyway.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:/@ALIAS

I am getting below error :

ERROR:

### Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource (jdbc:oracle:thin:/@ALIAS) for user 'null': IO Error: Unknown host specified

SQL State  : 08006
Error Code : 17002
Message    : IO Error: Unknown host specified

Can somebody help me to run flyway using oracle wallet.

Comment: There is no code i just try to execute a simple sql by using migrate command of flyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [SSL with Oracle JDBC Thin driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf) for more details.